# How to output php between header and woocommerce container

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, custom-header

I am customizing my product detail page.
I put the code before the single product summary in content-single-product.php

As you can see here: [Link to product page](https://www.importeermijnmercedes.nl/product/audi-a1-spb-1-6tdi-nav-vorb-fse-shz-sport/)

But i want it like this:

[image]

Can some one tell me where i have to put the code to place it outside the woocommerce container?

Thanks,

Chiel

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding php in index.php file in your theme folder after `get_header()` is called.Your php block will come after header and before woo commerce content.

Comment: yes this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The function responsible for opening WooCommerce content wrapper is attached to `woocommerce_before_main_content` action hook with priority 10.

You can wrap your code into function and attach it to that hook with priority less than 10.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'se337291_before_content_wrapper');
function se337291_before_content_wrapper()
{
   // display something only on single product page
   if ( ! is_product() ) 
      return;
   //
   // your code here...
   //
}
```

Another option is to copy the `single-product.php` file to the theme directory and modify it. [Here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1) you will find information on how to overwrite templates.